# How should I calculate the standard error of $S$?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, estimation, simulation

Suppose that you can assign $s$ employees on a project, where $s\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$. Suppose you simulate the progress of the project $n$ times for each $s$. You retrieve an estimate of the optimal $s^*$, by choosing the $s$ for which the number of times the employees completed the project was the largest. The probability that the project is completed would then be equal to $p_s =\dfrac{\text{number of succes}}{n}$, and if $n$ is large enough you find the standard error of the estimated probability with s.e. = $\dfrac{\sigma_s}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{p_s(1-p_s)}$.

**Question:** Suppose that you want to find the standard error of $s^*$, how would you proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to confuse $s$ with the number of successes in $n$ simulations.